# HKSampleQuery returns no results for HKSeriesType.workoutRoute

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit

The issue I'm facing is that I'm attempting to get the underlying GPS points from a running workout, but no workouts are found.

The first function, `fetchRunningWorkouts`, below completes fine, it is when `fetchRunningWorkoutRoute` fails with no data found. I can see there are runs available on the device and I can see that I have the proper authorization for the needed queries.

Note: For the sake of clarity I am calling `KHealthStore().execute()`

---

```
    func fetchRunningWorkouts() {
        // Create a predicate to filter for running workouts
        let workoutPredicate = HKQuery.predicateForWorkouts(with: .running)

        // Create a query to fetch running workouts
        let workoutQuery = HKSampleQuery(
            sampleType: HKWorkoutType.workoutType(),
            predicate: workoutPredicate,
            limit: 8,
            sortDescriptors: nil
        ) { (query, samples, error) in
             
             fetchRunningWorkoutRoute(workout: workout)
             ....
     }
```

---

```
func fetchRunningWorkoutRoute(workout: HKWorkout) {

    let workoutRouteQuery = HKSampleQuery(
        sampleType: HKSeriesType.workoutRoute(),
        predicate: HKQuery.predicateForObjects(from: workout),
        limit: HKObjectQueryNoLimit,
        sortDescriptors: nil
    ) { (query, samplesOrNil, errorOrNil) in
          guard errorOrNil == nil else {
              print("HealthKit query error: \(errorOrNil!.localizedDescription)")
              return
          }

        guard let samples = samplesOrNil as? [HKWorkoutRoute], let route = samples.first else {
            print("No workout route found in HealthKit.")
            return
        }
           ....
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone comes across this I figured it out. This is the updated function.

```
func getLastWorkouts() {
    let workoutType = HKSampleType.workoutType()

    let workoutQuery = HKSampleQuery(
        sampleType: workoutType,
        predicate: nil,
        limit: 10,
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(key: HKSampleSortIdentifierStartDate, ascending: false)]
    ) { (query, samples, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("HealthKit query error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }

        guard let workouts = samples as? [HKWorkout] else {
            print("No workouts found in HealthKit.")
            return
        }
        let quantityType = HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .distanceWalkingRunning)!

        for workout in workouts {
            if workout.workoutActivityType == .running {
                if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
                    for (quantityType, statistics) in workout.allStatistics {
                        print("Quantity Type: \(quantityType)")
                        print("Statistics: \(statistics)")
                        self.fetchRunningWorkoutRoute(workout: workout)
                    }
                } else {
                    // Fallback on earlier versions
                }
            }
        }
    }

    healthStore.execute(workoutQuery)
}
```